# Mongoose Updating mutual relationships

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working with 2 models:

Product and Event.

**Product** model has reference from Event (_id) 
**Event** model has reference from Product (_id).

So far I've found that if I want to update an Event and add or quit products, I have to update the Product model as-well using another operation. The same for delete (if I delete an event, I have to update the products that had that event associated and take them out).

My problem here is that for example:
I have a Product (id 1) that has event_id:[1,2,3,4}]
I have Event (id 1) that has a product_id: [1,2].

If I update the event (id 1) and take out the product 1, the Event now will have only product id 2, but the product will still have the event id 1.

For doing that I am using hooks: for updating that in particular I am doing this:

```
EventSchema.post("findOneAndUpdate", function(doc) {
  Product.updateMany({
    _id: {
      $in: doc.product
    }
  }, {
    event: doc._id.toString()
  }, {
    multi: true
  }, function(error, product) {
    if (error) console.log(error)
  })
})
```

How can I update the Product model, taking out the id in event_id column array? I hope my explanation in clear.

EVENT SHCEMA

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({

   client: {
   type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Client'
   }]
  },

  product: {
   type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product'
    }]
  },

     date: {
    type: Date,
    maxlength: 64,
     lowercase: true,
   trim: true
  },

  place: {
   type: String,
    maxlength: 1200,
   minlength: 1,
 },

  price: {
   type: Number
  },

  comment: {
    type: String,
   maxlength: 12000,
   minlength: 1,
  },
},
 {
   toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
 },
  {
   timestamps: true
 },
);
```

CLIENT SCHEMA

```
const ClientSchema = new Schema(
  {
    first_name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 1,
      required: [true, "Client first name is required"]
    },

    last_name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 1
    },

    address: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 1200,
      minlength: 1
    },

    phone: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 1
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true
    },

    web: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 1200,
      minlength: 1
    },

    comment: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 12000,
      minlength: 1
    },

    event: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Event"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

PRODUCT SCHEMA:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 1,
      required: [true, "Product name is required"]
    },

    description: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 12000,
      minlength: 1
    },

    comment: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 12000,
      minlength: 1
    },

    state: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 0
    },

    available: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    price: {
      type: Number
    },

    category: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Category"
        }
      ]
    },

    event: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Event"
        }
      ]
    },
    image: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Image"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

INPUT DATA: product/:id route

```
{
"available": false,
"category": [
    "5e04cd609b1c6812c8f9a9d1"
],
"event": [
    "5e07f73d72503f6659f40b26"
],
"image": [
    "5e05f9dd66432544b7bf0221"
],
"_id": "5e05f9d166432544b7bf0220",
"name": "Mesa ratona",
"price": 1200,
"comment": "-",
"description": "-",
"__v": 0,
"modelName": "Product",
"id": "5e05f9d166432544b7bf0220"
```

}

INPUT DATA event/:id

```
{
"client": [
    "5e05f743cd57804386a92a89"
],
"product": [
    "5e05f9d166432544b7bf0220",
    "5e06464b811a954e831eafcf",
    "5e064c5c811a954e831eafd3"
],
"_id": "5e07f73d72503f6659f40b26",
"date": "2020-01-12T00:45:33.069Z",
"place": "EVENT 1",
"price": 123,
"comment": "EVENT 1",
"__v": 0,
"id": "5e07f73d72503f6659f40b26"
```

}

INPUT DATA client/:id

```
{
"event": [
    "5e07f73d72503f6659f40b26"
],
"_id": "5e05f743cd57804386a92a89",
"first_name": "Ernesto",
"last_name": "De Lucía",
"address": "Calle Santa Fé 3129 Piso 5 Depto \"B\" Capital Federal",
"email": "ernestodl@gmail.com",
"phone": "+54 011 1567432984",
"web": "-",
"comment": "-",
"__v": 0,
"full_name": "Ernesto De Lucía",
"id": "5e05f743cd57804386a92a89"
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add Product and Event schema codes and sample input documents?

Comment: I am sorry, What do you mean with input data?

Comment: sample documents in json format

Comment: By the way I corrected min property to minlength in a few places for example in client.web field.

Comment: Perfect! thank you. I've already added some input data

Comment: it seems you have 3 schemas, product, client and event. Event schema and client sample document are missing. Can you add them to the question?

Comment: I am sorry my bad, I wanted to copy Event Schema and put Client Schema. I have already added Event Schema.

Comment: Nacho, I posted a very detailed answer. I already tested this, and it works. Please check it carefully,  and don't forget to mark it answer and upvote.

Comment: SuleymanSah, thank you so much, I took a look and looks really simple and clean, as soon as I have it working I will mark the answer and vote, so other people can use it (I looked everywhere and many people asking similar cases and I didn't find anything)

Comment: Ok, if you have any problem, write please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schemas there are many to many references, so when an items needs to be deleted it needs to be deleted from all the referenced documents.

I suggest you to remove that many to many references, by using [virtual populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).

I simplified the schemas to include only the required fields.

Event: ( I removed the references to the products and clients, and used virtual populate)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EventSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

// Virtual populate
EventSchema.virtual("clients", {
  ref: "Client",
  foreignField: "events",
  localField: "_id"
});

EventSchema.virtual("products", {
  ref: "Product",
  foreignField: "events",
  localField: "_id"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Event", EventSchema);
```

Client:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClientSchema = new Schema(
  {
    first_name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 1,
      required: [true, "Client first name is required"]
    },
    events: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Event"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Client", ClientSchema);
```

Product:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 64,
      minlength: 1,
      required: [true, "Product name is required"]
    },
    events: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Event"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

I have these sample documents:

Events:

```
{
    "_id": "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542",
    "name": "Event 1",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
}
{
    "_id": "5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543",
    "name": "Event 2",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543"
}
```

Products:

```
{
    "events": [
        "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542",
        "5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543"
    ],
    "_id": "5e08cf9de9dfcc0e1431c90b",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08cf9de9dfcc0e1431c90b"
}
{
    "events": [
        "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
    ],
    "_id": "5e08cfa9e9dfcc0e1431c90c",
    "name": "Product 2",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08cfa9e9dfcc0e1431c90c"
}
```

Clients:

```
{
    "events": [
        "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542",
        "5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543"
    ],
    "_id": "5e08cfdce9dfcc0e1431c90e",
    "first_name": "Client 1",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08cfdce9dfcc0e1431c90e"
}
{
    "events": [
        "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
    ],
    "_id": "5e08cfece9dfcc0e1431c90f",
    "first_name": "Client 2",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08cfece9dfcc0e1431c90f"
}
```

Let's first solve the problem of accessing clients and products from event since we removed that references.

We can use the following route to get events with its clients and products virtual populated:

```
router.get("/events/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Event.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("clients")
    .populate("products");

  res.send(result);
});
```

The response will be like this: (as you see even though we removed the references we could access clients and products using virtual populate)

```
{
    "_id": "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542",
    "name": "Event 1",
    "__v": 0,
    "clients": [
        {
            "events": [
                "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542",
                "5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543"
            ],
            "_id": "5e08cfdce9dfcc0e1431c90e",
            "first_name": "Client 1",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5e08cfdce9dfcc0e1431c90e"
        },
        {
            "events": [
                "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
            ],
            "_id": "5e08cfece9dfcc0e1431c90f",
            "first_name": "Client 2",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5e08cfece9dfcc0e1431c90f"
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "events": [
                "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542",
                "5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543"
            ],
            "_id": "5e08cf9de9dfcc0e1431c90b",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5e08cf9de9dfcc0e1431c90b"
        },
        {
            "events": [
                "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
            ],
            "_id": "5e08cfa9e9dfcc0e1431c90c",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5e08cfa9e9dfcc0e1431c90c"
        }
    ],
    "id": "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
}
```

Now to remove an event from a product  or client, we need to just remove from there.

For example to delete an event from a product, we just need to delete it from product:

```
router.delete("/products/:id/:eventId", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $pull: {
        events: req.params.eventId
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  res.send(result);
});
```

Before this delete, this product had 2 events with ids `5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542` and `5e08cec5a62f094ba4ca2543`.
After we delete it will only have one event with id `5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542`:

```
{
    "events": [
        "5e08ceb5a62f094ba4ca2542"
    ],
    "_id": "5e08cf9de9dfcc0e1431c90b",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e08cf9de9dfcc0e1431c90b"
}
```